# Automatically init rolling update of kubernetes deployment when there is a new version of container image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a kubernetes deployment that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: datacollector
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      pod-type: datacollector
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        pod-type: datacollector
    spec:
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: secret
      containers:
        - name: datacollector
          image: "build.dorangg.dev/doranggdatacollector:latest"
          imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Currently I run the following command whenever I want to update the deployment to use the newest version of the image from the docker registry (build.dorangg.dev) :

```
kubectl rollout restart deployment/datacollector
```

I want to initiate a rolling update of the deployment (what the above command does) AUTOMATICALLY whenever a new version of the image appears in the docker registry.

Can this be accomplished using the kubernetes configuration? If not, is this automation possible to do with a script?

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be accomplished using the kubernetes configuration?

I don't know.

> If not, is this automation possible to do with a script?

Yes. You do a `docker pull` on the image. If docker pulls a new image then you delete the POD with `kubectl` and then it gets redeployed.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I don't think it can be configured inside the Kubernetes. It will need additional scripts/triggers.

Options comes to my mind, but you need to "catch" new of the new image with script (for example name of new image after successfull push to repository).

**- Patch deployment**

```
$ kubectl patch deployment [your-deployment] -p \
'{"spec":{"template":{"spec":{"image":"[new-image-name:tag]"}}}}'
```

Kubernetes if will see some changes it should redeploy whole deployment.

**- Create script with set new image**

```
$ kubectl set image deployment/[deployment-name] [image-name]=[new-image-name:tag]
```

After this change kubernetes should also redeploy all pods.

**- Use HELM**

As helm using Charts and Templates you can create script which will change image name in `values.yaml` and redeploy it.

**- Patch GracePeriod**

If you want to keep the same image name all the time, you can try to patch `GracePeriod`.
It was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40366192/kubernetes-how-to-make-deployment-to-update-image).

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do this is to use `kubectl set image` to tell the deployment there is a new image, but it won't work if you are using `:latest` because the deployment won't trigger if the tag doesn't change. It's bad idea using `:latest` in general anyway, so you would have to move to semversioning of the tags for your containers.